# Изменение нумерации в базе данных SQLite

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Я начинающий программист.

У меня приложение-словарь. База данных составлена в SQLite. По мере добавления новых слов, порядковая нумерация (или ID, первая колонка с нумерацией) изменилась, так что слова при поиске появляются не по алфавиту. Как можно исправить эту нумерацию, чтобы слова отображались по алфавитному порядку? Вручную очень долго и трудоемко.

Для наглядности, база вводилась так:

```
insert into eng_p(id, eng, pron, pron_1, pron_2, uzb, uzb_1, uzb_2) 
values(*id*, 'eng', 'pron', 'pron_1', 'pron_2', 'uzb', 'uzb_1', 'uzb_2';).
```

Нужно изменить `*id*`, после values.

Надеюсь, смог объяснить.

Comment: может быть, правильнее использовать orderBy?

Comment: А можно поподробнее ,плиз? Я не кодер, поэтому буду благодарен за подробный и детальный совет.

Comment: посмотрите там - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/76-urok-36-sqlite-podrobnee-pro-metod-query-uslovie-sortirovka-gruppirovka.html

Comment: Наверное, я не четко задал вопрос. Если orderBy - это сортировать, то мне это не подходит. Мне нужно задать новую нумерацию, если это возможно, то есть вместо старой начать заново. Скриншот бы очень помог понять, что я имею в виду, но здесь не могу добавить.

Comment: id - уникальный идентификатор записи, а не порядковый номер. Он не предназначен для сортировки, а только для однозначной идентификации записи. Более того, изменение id записи - грубейшее нарушение принципов построения СУБД. Как номер паспорта, никто не переписывает номера паспорта по алфавиту.

Answer (score 2):

@Akbar - в SQL отсутствует понятие порядка/нумерации данных в БД/таблице.

Порядок определяется только выводом, а для этого существует ключевое слово при запросе `order by`

В вашем случае вам нужно всего лишь устроить вывод в виде запроса:

```
select id, eng, pron, pron_1, pron_2, uzb, uzb_1, uzb_2 from eng_p order by eng asc
```

В итоге вы получите ту же самую таблицу отсортированную по полю `eng` в порядке возрастания.

Comment: по Вашему совету в самой базе данных получилось (отражается по алфавиту). А в приложении будет теперь так же отражаться, как и в базе данных?

Comment: В каком приложении? Впрочем это неважно - в приложении будет отображаться смотря какой `select` вы ему дадите.

Answer (score 1):

База данных ищет данные как ей удобно если нету соответствующего индекса.
Как я понимая вам необходимо что бы порядок `ID` и соответствовал алфавиту слов  в поле `eng`.
К примеру можно сделать курсор и обновить поле `ID`